# Passing selected value from the radio buttons to the controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to pass this selected radio button value from the razor view to the controller.... 
can someone please give me an idea how to do this?.....................
My View looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Exam"))
{

    @Html.Hidden("qid", Model.ID, new { @id = "id" })
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Model.ID
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.QuestionDes
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>@Html.RadioButton("Answer1", new { @id = 1 })  @Model.Answer1 </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>@Html.RadioButton("Answer2", new { @id = 2 })  @Model.Answer2 </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>@Html.RadioButton("Answer3", new { @id = 3 })  @Model.Answer3 </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>@Html.RadioButton("Answer4", new { @id = 4 })  @Model.Answer4 </p>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Next" />

}
@using (Html.BeginForm("PrevIndex", "Exam"))
{

    @Html.Hidden("qid1", Model.ID, new { @id = "id1" })
    <input value="Prev" type="submit" />
}
```

My Controller looks like this:.........

```
 public class ExamController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IQuestionService ser = new QuestionService();
            QuestionLoadDTO q = ser.GetIndividualQuestions(1);
            return View(q);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(QuestionLoadDTO ques)
        {
            int count = 0;
            count = int.Parse(Request["qid"].ToString());
            count++;
            if (count <= 4)
            {
                IQuestionService ser = new QuestionService();
                QuestionLoadDTO q = ser.GetIndividualQuestions(count);
                return View(q);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Submit");

        }
        public ActionResult PrevIndex(QuestionLoadDTO ques)
        {
            int count1 = 0;
            count1 = int.Parse(Request["qid1"].ToString());
            count1--;
            if (count1 < 5 || count1 >= 0)
            {
                IQuestionService ser = new QuestionService();
                QuestionLoadDTO q = ser.GetIndividualQuestions(count1);
                return View("Index", q);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("End");

        }
        public ActionResult Submit()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult End()
        {
            return View();
        }




    }
```

These are the other methods:

```
QuestionLoadDTO IQuestionService.GetIndividualQuestions(int index)
{
    IQuestionData ser = new QuestionRepository();           

    QuestionLoadDTO q = ser.GetIndividualQues(index);

    return q;
}
public QuestionLoadDTO GetIndividualQues(int index)
{
    Context con = new Context();
    Question question = con.Questions.Find(index);//Where(e => e.ID == index).FirstOrDefault();
    QuestionLoadDTO dto = new QuestionLoadDTO()
    {
        ID = question.ID,
        QuestionDes = question.QuestionDes,
        Answer1 = question.Answer1,
        Answer2 = question.Answer2,
        Answer3 = question.Answer3,
        Answer4 = question.Answer4

    };                                
    return dto;
}
```

Thank you!!!!

Comment: Make hidden feilds for every question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add property:

```
public string SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
```

Add in view:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedAnswer, "Answer1")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedAnswer, "Answer2")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedAnswer, "Answer3")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedAnswer, "Answer4")
```

In controller it postback the value according to selected radio button... i.e. either Answer1, or Answer2, etc.

Comment: Does `SelectedAnswer` has to be the model for that View? What if I have other model?

Answer (score 8):

If you are giving same name for your radio buttons, then you can try the following code

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Answer)
{
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Demo"))
{
       @Html.RadioButton("Answer", "A") <span>A</span> 
       @Html.RadioButton("Answer", "B") <span>B</span> 

    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
}
```

Comment: i have generated runtime RadioButtons is there any method for passing them to controller ?

Comment: is there a way to set the radio button to selected when clicking on the text? at the moment it's only when clicking on the actual circle that it gets set

Answer (score 3):

Either make a hidden field for every radio button or change you radio buttons like this

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor("Answer1", new { @id = 1 })
```

Answer (score 3):

Use form collection

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fc)
    {

      string answerA = fc["Answer1"];
      string answerB = fc["Answer2"];
      string answerC = fc["Answer3"];
      string answerD = fc["Answer4"];
      return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I saw this on another thread and it work like a champ.

Razor view like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("test", "testcontroller"))
{
  @Html.RadioButton("CashPayment", "1")<span>Yes</span>
  @Html.RadioButton("CashPayment", "0")<span>No</span>
}
```

And Controller like this:

```
public ActionResult test(string CashPayment)
{   
   //your code
}
```

Comment: s there a way to set the radio button to selected when clicking on the text? at the moment it's only when clicking on the actual circle that it gets set

Answer (score 2):

Add the following source code to View:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Role, "1" ) <span>A</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Role, "0" ) <span>B</span>
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Role)
```

You can put the selected value to this HiddenField: `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Role)` and send it to controller via [HttpPost] prototype.