# MVC Razor Need to find which radio option is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

The form:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Daily Details", "ViewDaily")
<div class="ca-form-layout">
                <table class="ca-index-table" style="margin:10px auto">
                    <tr class="ca-header-row">
                        <th class="ca-header-cell" style="width:60px"></th>
                        <th class="ca-header-cell" style="width:140px">Date</th>
                        <th class="ca-header-cell" style="width:140px">Payment Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var gr in groups)
                    {
                        <tr class="ca-table-row">
                            <td class="ca-table-cell" align="center">@Html.RadioButton("payDate", gr.Key.ToShortDateString())</td>
                            <td class="ca-table-cell" align="center">@Html.FormatValue(gr.Key, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")</td>
                            <td class="ca-table-cell" align="center">@Html.FormatValue(gr.Sum(p => p.PaymentAmount), "{0:C}")</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

From my controller, how do I get the value from the payDate radioButton?  I was trying to use FormCollection["payDate"] but wasn't getting any value to come through that way.  I know there must be some easy answer, but I can't find it anywhere.

Note:  If I replace the radioButton with this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Daily Details", "ViewDaily", new { prmDate = gr.Key })
```

... the page works perfectly fine so there is nothing wrong with any of the values, routing or controller ... I just can't get that value to pass without specifying it directly in the ActionLink.  There are 3 other buttons that all need to work off the RadioButton so I can't simply just replace it with a single button.

Thanks

Comment: please look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700101/passing-selected-value-from-the-radio-buttons-to-the-controller-in-mvc post

Answer (score 0):

There's no actual form here, so there's nothing sending that value to the server.

To create a form with form elements (such as a radio button), you'd wrap it in something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewDaily", "SomeControllerName"))
{
    <!--- Your HTML goes here, including form elements --->
}
```

Included within that form scope would generally be a submit button, something like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewDaily", "SomeControllerName"))
{
    <!--- Your HTML goes here, including form elements --->
    <input type="submit" value="View Daily Details" />
}
```

Which of course you could style to look like whatever you want.  If you *really* want the "submit" to be a link then you'd need to write some JavaScript to turn that request (which is otherwise a GET) into a form POST.  But just using a submit button would be considerably easier.

This would wrap your form in the requisite `<form>` tag so that the browser knows to send the key/value pairs to the server.